# ContainerView embedded in ViewController: Outlets are nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

As I am trying to update a container view content from its parent view controller with a function.

After updating the initial ViewDidLoad sets. The app crashes.
It seems like all Outlets become nil

Comment: what do you mean by update? The app crash with what error ? the Outlets are nil or become nil (can you print something in viewDidLoad before the crash if yes give us what is inside you're viewDidLoad)? What do you have in the Container view ?

Comment: I've got a fine working Parse Query. It works when i got a single View Controller without container views. It is in terms of UI better to have a container. Everytime I swipe the Container View controller an Update function is called, which refreshes the Labels and Images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the view controller in the container view and then you should have access to all its outlets.  Assign a segue identifier to the segue to the container view controller and get a reference when the segue is called.

For example to update a label in the container view controller from a button in the parent view controller.

Parent view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var containerVC : ContainerVC!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if (segue.identifier == "segueContainer")
        {
            containerVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainerVC
        }
    }


@IBAction func butUpdateContainerLabelAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if containerVC != nil{
           containerVC.lblDemo.text = "some new text"
       }
    }

}
```

Container View Controller

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lblDemo: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me :)!