# Swift containerview loses mapView outlet

Tags: ios, swift

Have a container view with a embedded VC and within it a view of GMSMapView set as

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
```

Within viewDidLoad of the embedded VC I set the delegate, etc.

```
mapView.delegate = self
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = false
mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)
mapView.settings.compassButton = false
```

The parent VC then calls a function in the embedded VC after getting the data. Within the function I create a marker but the mapView is now nil.

mapView is correctly wired up. If I don't call the function, the map shows.

Within the function doing

```
print(mapView)
```

results in nil or even removing the weak on the outlet is still nil

I'm at a lost of the cause. Anyone have an idea of what would cause the mapView to be nil?

---

Missed the solution in my search. Found the solution on another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922428/containerview-embedded-in-viewcontroller-outlets-are-nil?rq=1) question. My apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: Are you calling `super.viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: @brandonscript I am but cause was something else. Updated question with the answer. Sorry for your time.